# Missing table cell borders in IE 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is a problem in Internet Explorer 7 only (and maybe earlier versions of IE).
Here is the problematic page:
http://wwwtest.vishay.com/mosfets/mosfet-hirel-dev/index.html

The horizontal line between the two products listed in the first column is *not* shown (in IE7). It is shown in Firefox and Google Chrome.

I already played with the following:

1. `border-collapse:collapse;`
2. adding `&nbsp;` to the `TD`

The line does appear when I remove the following (unrelated?!) CSS:

```
table.list-table th {
    border:1px solid #eee;
    border-right:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:1px;
}
```

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
table{ 
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

table.list-table th {
    border:1px solid #eee;
    border-right:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already had tried that without luck.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not seeing what it could be :S

Comment: I will have to analyze more, but it may be that it happens only if there are only "2 rows" (and the spans).

Comment: Suspicion is confirmed. It looks like an IE 7 bug to me now. As soon as there is a third product (third "row") in the table, the separation borders are displayed. Please have a look yourselves (2nd link has a third fake product - nothing else changed):  
http://wwwtest.vishay.com/mosfets/so-16-package/index.html  
http://wwwtest.vishay.com/mosfets/so-16-package/index-alex.html